# How can I find and remove WordPress malware resulting in URLs with this styling: / top:0; left:-9999px

Tags: wordpress, html, url, security, malware

I'm breaking my head for 2 days with this one, and would appreciate some extra thoughts.

These links are found in wp-content/cache/wp-rocket .html files only, while they are not present on the actual real-time pages.

I have tried searching in all files various strings: -9999, thewpclub, sorry_function. I searched through the database, but could not find anything at all.

WordFence & Sucuri are not finding any weird script within the files.

This was the closest problem someone had:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901355/malicious-text-appears-in-all-pages-and-posts-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it

`<a href="https://www.thewpclub.net">Premium WordPress Themes Download</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://www.themeslide.com">Download WordPress Themes Free</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://www.script-stack.com">Download WordPress Themes</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://www.thememazing.com">Premium WordPress Themes Download</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://www.onlinefreecourse.net">free download udemy paid course</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://www.frendx.com/firmware/">download xiomi firmware</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://www.themebanks.com">Download WordPress Themes Free</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://downloadtutorials.net">udemy free download</a></div></div></div></div>`

Comment: If it is malware, you likely won't find the string by searching as it is usually encoded in an attempt to hide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I managed to solve it.

I know that "one size fits all" is not the case with malware. I asked for extra thoughts as someone might have a hint how to approach it as I'm well informed and capable of dealing with these situations through the years.

After numerous failed attempts to search various strings, trying to encode few words in hex and search those, searching through plugins etc. I inspected the cached `.html` file and noticed that these links were hidden under WooCommerce `delivery-info` div.

I then searched delivery-info string through all the WP files and I got around 50 hits. I found a suspicious line that one of the developers added, which was calling `delivery-info` div together with `$content` string.

I then searched `$content` string through all the plugins with numerous hits. After searching for a while I finally found the script that was causing it. It was hidden in WPBakery - js-composer/include/inc.php file which should not have existed. One of the lines from the file:

`$abc1 = '' . $divclass . '<a href="'.sanitize_context_zero("aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhld3BjbHViLm5ldA==").'">' . $array[array_rand($array) ] . '</a></div>';`

I deleted that file & then searched `inc.php` with a hit in `js-composer.php` calling for it.

Comment: Nice work and thanks for sharing the technique, hopefully it will help others.  It is scary that you suspect a developer did this.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm using the WPBakery plugin but that file isn't in that location anymore. Any idea where the offending code is now?